# Getting an error when try to execute java function

Tags: java

I have created a java function to do some calculations. But i am getting error as follows

> Solution.java:#line_num: error: cannot find symbol
>           double a=count1/arr.length;
>                    ^   symbol:   variable count1   location: class Solution Solution.java:#line_num: error: cannot find symbol
>           double b=count2/arr.length;
>                    ^   symbol:   variable count2   location: class Solution Solution.java:#line_num: error: cannot find symbol
>           double c=count3/arr.length;
>                    ^   symbol:   variable count3   location: class Solution 3 errors

as my code i getting input from users and pass data to function. But i cant recognize what us the issue.
I have mentioned my function below

```
static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        int count1=0;
        int count2=0;
        int count3=0;

        if(arr[i]>0){
            count1++;
        }
        else if(arr[i]<0){
            count2++;
        }
        else{
            count3++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count1/arr.length);
    System.out.println(count2/arr.length);
    System.out.println(count3/arr.length);

}
```

Comment: what kind of a question is this. Please go and learn your basics before  posting the question. This form is not to teach you coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created & initialized `count1`  `count2` and `count3` inside the for loop and used outside

Declare it globally to access it from everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You have to declare `count1`, `count2` and `count3` outside the for loop.

```
static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    int count3=0;

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]>0){
            count1++;
        }
        else if(arr[i]<0){
            count2++;
        }
        else{
            count3++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count1/arr.length);
    System.out.println(count2/arr.length);
    System.out.println(count3/arr.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the 3 variables, `count1`, `count2` and `count3` outside both the `for` loops, so they are accessible anywhere inside the function. You may initialize or change their values inside the loops when needed. But declaration needs to be done outside.

```
static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
        int count1=0;
        int count2=0;
        int count3=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

        if(arr[i]>0){
            count1++;
        }
        else if(arr[i]<0){
            count2++;
        }
        else{
            count3++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count1/arr.length);
    System.out.println(count2/arr.length);
    System.out.println(count3/arr.length);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

count1  count2 and count3  variable create in Outside of the Loop.

Declare it globally to access it from everywhere